# Get n repositories with most stars out of a given organization - Github API

Tags: github, github-api

What's the easiest way to get the 'most starred' repositories out of a given organization using the Github API? Is there a parameter option for this? I'm currently making a request to

```
http://api.github.com/orgs/ORGANIZATION/repos
```

and then filtering with my own code, but I wondered if the Github team implemented anything like that already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [search API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#search-repositories), specify your org and sort by stars:

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=org:YOUR_ORGg&sort=stars&order=desc
```

Example: https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=org:mui-org&sort=stars&order=desc

You can limit to the top X repo using `per_page` (if X < 100). For instance to get the top 3 repo with most stars in the org `mui-org`:

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=org:mui-org&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=3